# Simple Injector terminology clarify

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, simple-injector

In Simple Injector [documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#transient) is sentence: "A new instance of the service type will be created for each ***request*** (both for calls to GetInstance and instances as part of an object graph).".

I'm little bit confused, what request means? - Is it request like *http request* or it is *request to resolve service (instance)* from container?

In part of [singleton](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#singleton) is term ***lifetime***; lifetime is defined by `container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebApiRequestLifestyle();`?

Comment: I agree. The use of 'request' is confusing. In the context of that paragraph, 'request' means 'someone requesting an instance from the container'. So you request an insrance using GetInstance and you can request an instance using a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 2):

By default `Transient` is used which means every time you request the type a new instance will be created.

You can also use `Web Request` if you want to reuse the instance for the whole web request.

http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#perwebrequest

Comment: Thank you for response, but I'm still confused; let me ask you about Singleton - if I use web request lifetime, Singleton instance is created only for one user and one user only or is Singleton shared across any user's requests - Singleton will be alive until I restart IIS? To be clear, my use case is create Unit of work manager, but this manager must be only one per request and not shares across requests...

Comment: `Singleton` does only create a instance per the liftetime of the application. So everyone is getting the same instance. A new instance is only created if the appool is recycled or you restart the website.

Comment: I've tested what you say, but unfortunately you are wrong. SI Container with `WebRequestLifestyle` by default returns new instance on every request for service from container. If you want to use same instance you have to specify `Lifestyle.Scoped`. Anyway, thank you for your responses, you definitely help me to better understand Simple Injector!

Comment: `WebRequestLifestyle` will return a new on every web request. So if you request a instance several time during the web requerst, you will get the same instance. The default regarding to the documentation is `Transient` which always returns a new instance, even if it is in the same web request or not.

If you don't add a liftestyle-configuration the `Transient` are used.

Comment: Not true. See [GitLab test project](https://gitlab.com/SebastianBusek/si-test) and in Global.asax.cs find line #22. At first start application and you should see "A > B" (in aplication is used same instance of `IStackManager` and try to remove `Lifestyle.Scoped` from line #22 a you will see just "A" - new instance of `IStackManager` is used on every request.

Comment: Not sure I understand you. Regarding to the documentation I provided in my answer above, if you want `Web Request` you are setting it up with `Lifestyle.Scoped`. Maybe I should clarify that if I was clear.

Comment: @Merryweather: If an instance is registered per `WebRequestLifestyle`, there will be only one instance per web request *per container*. If your register an instance as `Singleton`, there will only one instance *per container*. So if you create multiple `Container` instances, there will be multiple instances. You will however, usually create just a single container instance for the duration of the lifetime of your application.